# Java Timestamp with Fractional Seconds

Tags: java, decimal, unix-timestamp, java.time.instant

How can I print Java `Instant` as a timestamp with fractional seconds like 1558766955.037 ? The precision needed is to 1/1000, as the example shows.

I tried `(double) timestamp.getEpochSecond() + (double) timestamp.getNano() / 1000_000_000`, but when I convert it to string and print it, it shows `1.558766955037E9`.

Comment: It sounds like this is a *display* issue as much as anything else - if you write `double value = 1558766955.037;` and print that, I suspect you'll get the same result. So at that point, the problem isn't around timestamps - it's number formatting. I expect you'll find some other Stack Overflow questions around that.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's actually correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're seeing is the [secientific (e-) notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) of the result you wanted to get. In other words, you have the right result, you just need to properly format it when you print it:

```
Instant timestamp = Instant.now();
double d = (double) timestamp.getEpochSecond() + (double) timestamp.getNano() / 1000_000_000;
System.out.printf("%.2f", d);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out it is formatting issue. For your specific format you could use `Formatter` with `Locale` that supports dot delimetted fractions :

```
Instant now = Instant.now();

double val = (double) now.getEpochSecond() + (double) now.getNano() / 1000_000_000;

String value = new Formatter(Locale.US)
                .format("%.3f", val)
                .toString();

System.out.print(value);
```

Prints :

```
1558768149.514
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.printf("%.3f", instant.toEpochMilli() / 1000.0)` should work.